# Java: Validate textfield input if it only contains alphabetic characters

Tags: java, regex, character-properties

How do I validate if a text only contains alphabetic characters?

I think we can use `Pattern.matches()` but I don't know the regular expression for alphabetic characters.

Comment: Is the textfield allowed to be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a category for alphabetics, combined with `matches`, and delimiters for the beginning and end of input text, as such:

```
String valid = "abc";
String invalid = "abc3";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Alpha}+$"); // use \\p{L} for Unicode support
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valid);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
matcher = pattern.matcher(invalid);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Note: this also happens to prevent empty inputs. If you want to allow them, use a different quantifier than `+`, namely, `*`.

Finally, since you will use that against a `java.awt.TextField`, you can simply access its text with the method `getText()`.

Comment: You need to use `(?U)` if you expect that to match non-ASCII alphabetics.

Comment: @tchrist actually the `?U` flag is invalid. You're probably thinking of `?u`, and that wouldn't work with my solution either. But thanks for pointing Unicode support out, I've adapted my answer.

Comment: No, I’m thinking of `(?U)` from Java 7. Before then, Java regexes really didn’t work well with Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you used **JFormattedTextField**

here's more info in it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html